# How to lock an overlayed image to an element

Tags: tumblr

I want to lock an overlayed image on a Tumblr blog in a position relevant to my sidebar and body content. However, everything I've tried results on the image locking to the side of the window, thus, when the browser window is resized and the distance between the posts and the window changes, the position of the image relevant to the sidebar where I want it changes as well.

I don't know the language very well so please try to explain in as basic terms as you would for a beginner.

[full screen (where I want the image to stay)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D79T4.jpg)

[minimized browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zOMSr.jpg)

```css
#sidebar {
    box-shadow:rgba(0,0,0,0.1)5px 5px;
    text-align:left;
    position:fixed;
    {block:ifnotrightsidebar}
    margin-left:-225px;
    {block:ifnotrightsidebar}
    {block:ifrightsidebar}
    margin-left:485px;
    {block:ifrightsidebar}
    border:1px solid #d1d1d1;
    background:#fff;
    bottom:20px;
    width:150px;
    padding:5px;
    {block:ifroundededges}
    border-radius:5px;
    {block:ifroundededges}}
    
    
#outsideimg {
    position:fixed;
    float:right;
    right:-40px;
    top:100px;


}



 
#outsideimg img {
    width:400px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the image inside the sidebar div and then position it absolutely. It will then stay with the sidebar (and when you position it, it will be relative to the sidebar and not the window).